# Root cause of java.net.ConnectException / java.net.SocketException

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

We’re using an apache CachingHttpClient with a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager configured and all accessed via a Spring RestTemplate.

Most of our connectivity is from Azure -> on-prem service using the same url. Under production load we get occasional exceptions above showing “Connection timed out: connect” or “connect timed out”, they both share the same root cause:

Java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect

We’ve had a few stabs at configuring the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with maxConnections/maxConnectionsPerRoute. From default 20/2 -> 40/8

This has improved our application throughput but still some connections timeout.

What I’m struggling with is knowing whether waitForConnect means the 40/8 config is throttling our application and connections are waiting for free routes OR the pooled connection / route is free but there is network latency preventing the connection from being made.

I hope that makes sense. I have debug logging on the  apache classes but it’s still not clear to me.

Comment: You did not mention what else is running on the same OS. Maybe it is struggling with too many parallel TCP connections.

Comment: It means your server isn't accepting connections fast enough. Maybe it is overloaded?

Comment: It would be helpful to rule out java here, if waitForConnect -> timeout is now a bottleneck outside of the JVM, unrelated to apache http client config, I can get a different team involved to run a network trace for example.